# delete post please

Tags: discussion

I would like that my post [Consecutive steps to get the posterior of parameters : 1) determine fiducials, 2) Fisher information's formalism, 3) Validation with MCMC estimation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/577100/consecutive-steps-to-get-the-posterior-of-parameters-1-determine-fiducials-2) to be deleted please. Could a moderator perform this ?

Thanks in advance, Regards

Comment: If any question counts as yours and has no upvoted answer, you should be able to delete it yourself.

Comment: @NickCox . I don't understand, the post is locked, I can't delete it

Comment: OK, so you need more help and should get it here in Meta

Comment: @NickCox I have contacted Meta and it seems they can't do nothing about the deleting or removing of my post.

Answer (score 8):

The relevant sequence of events is

1. it was migrated to Cross Validated;
2. it was closed on Cross Validated (because it needed more focus);
3. the migration was rejected (because it was closed).

Locking happens whenever a migration is rejected.

Eventually, the robots will delete the post. This is explained in [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered, zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006)

Because this question pertains to how the Stack Exchange software works, the best place to ask about it is Meta.Stackexchange. Please note that moderators have no power to change how the software works.